# Applying reduce on an object and getting a set of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have an object that I need to transform it, using reduce, but cannot manage to do it...
I have the following object:

```
const object = {
    set: {
        subset: [
        {
            subset_X: 1,
            algorithms: [
                {
                    type: "algorithm_A",
                    params: {
                        algorithm_A_param_1: 0.1,
                        algorithm_A_param_2: 0.2
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: "algorithm_B",
                    params: {
                        algorithm_B_param_1: 0.3,
                        algorithm_B_param_2: 0.4
                    }
                }
            ],
            subset_collection: [
                {
                    collection_X: 1,
                    algorithms: [
                        {
                            type: "algorithm_a",
                            params: {
                                algorithm_a_param_1: 0.5,
                                algorithm_a_param_2: 0.6
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: "algorithm_b",
                            params: {
                                algorithm_b_param_1: 0.7,
                                algorithm_b_param_2: 0.8
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    collection_subcollection: [
                        {
                            start: 1,
                            algorithms: [
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_1",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_1_param_1: 10,
                                        algorithm_1_param_2: 20
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_11",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_11_param_1: 30,
                                        algorithm_11_param_2: 40
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            start: 2,
                            algorithms: [
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_1",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_1_param_1: 50,
                                        algorithm_1_param_2: 60
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_11",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_11_param_1: 70,
                                        algorithm_11_param_2: 80
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    collection_X: 2,
                    algorithms: [
                        {
                            type: "algorithm_a",
                            params: {
                                algorithm_a_param_1: 0.9,
                                algorithm_a_param_2: 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: "algorithm_b",
                            params: {
                                algorithm_b_param_1: 1.1,
                                algorithm_b_param_2: 1.2
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    collection_subcollection: [
                        {
                            start: 1,
                            algorithms: [
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_1",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_1_param_1: 90,
                                        algorithm_1_param_2: 100
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_11",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_11_param_1: 110,
                                        algorithm_11_param_2: 120
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            start: 2,
                            algorithms: [
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_1",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_1_param_1: 130,
                                        algorithm_1_param_2: 140
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_11",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_11_param_1: 150,
                                        algorithm_11_param_2: 160
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            subset_X: 2,            
            alg: [
                {
                    type: "algorithm_C",
                    params: {
                        algorithm_C_param_1: 1.3,
                        algorithm_C_param_2: 1.4
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: "algorithm_D",
                    params: {
                        algorithm_D_param_1: 1.5,
                        algorithm_D_param_2: 1.6
                    }
                }
            ],
            subset_collection: [
                {
                    collection_X: 1,
                    alg: [
                        {
                            type: "algorithm_a",
                            params: {
                                algorithm_a_param_1: 1.7,
                                algorithm_a_param_2: 1.8
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: "algorithm_b",
                            params: {
                                algorithm_b_param_1: 1.9,
                                algorithm_b_param_2: 2
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    collection_subcollection: [
                        {
                            start: 1,
                            algorithms: [
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_1",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_1_param_1: 170,
                                        algorithm_1_param_2: 180
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_11",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_11_param_1: 190,
                                        algorithm_11_param_2: 200
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            start: 2,
                            algorithms: [
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_1",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_1_param_1: 210,
                                        algorithm_1_param_2: 220
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_11",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_11_param_1: 230,
                                        algorithm_11_param_2: 240
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    collection_X: 2,
                    alg: [
                        {
                            type: "algorithm_a",
                            params: {
                                algorithm_a_param_1: 2.1,
                                algorithm_a_param_2: 2.2
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: "algorithm_b",
                            params: {
                                algorithm_b_param_1: 2.3,
                                algorithm_b_param_2: 2.4
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    collection_subcollection: [
                        {
                            start: 1,
                            algorithms: [
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_1",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_1_param_1: 250,
                                        algorithm_1_param_2: 260
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_11",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_11_param_1: 270,
                                        algorithm_11_param_2: 280
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            start: 2,
                            algorithms: [
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_1",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_1_param_1: 290,
                                        algorithm_1_param_2: 300
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    type: "algorithm_11",
                                    params: {
                                        algorithm_11_param_1: 310,
                                        algorithm_11_param_2: 320
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I need to obtain is an object with its properties/fields as a concatenation of multiple fields from the initial object: "subset_X:collection_X:start:algorithm_{X}"

I need to obtain the following object:

```
{
    "1:::algorithm_A": {
        algorithm_A_param_1: 0.1,
        algorithm_A_param_2: 0.2
    },
    "1:::algorithm_A": {
        algorithm_A_param_1: 0.3,
        algorithm_A_param_2: 0.4
    },
    "1:1:1:algorithm_1": {
        algorithm_1_param_1: 10,
        algorithm_1_param_2: 20
    },
    "1:1:1:algorithm_11": {
        algorithm_11_param_1: 30,
        algorithm_11_param_2: 40
    },
    "1:1::algorithm_a": {
        algorithm_a_param_1: 0.5,
        algorithm_a_param_2: 0.6
    },
    "1:1::algorithm_b": {
        algorithm_b_param_1: 0.7,
        algorithm_b_param_2: 0.8
    },
    "1:1:2:algorithm_1": {
        algorithm_1_param_1: 50,
        algorithm_1_param_2: 60
    },
    "1:1:2:algorithm_11": {
        algorithm_11_param_1: 70,
        algorithm_11_param_2: 80
    },
    "1:2::algorithm_a": {
        algorithm_a_param_1: 0.9,
        algorithm_a_param_2: 1
    },
    "1:2::algorithm_b": {
        algorithm_b_param_1: 1.1,
        algorithm_b_param_2: 1.2
    },
    "1:2:1:algorithm_1": {
        algorithm_1_param_1: 90,
        algorithm_1_param_2: 100
    },
    "1:2:1:algorithm_11": {
        algorithm_11_param_1: 110,
        algorithm_11_param_2: 120
    },
    "1:2:2:algorithm_1": {
        algorithm_1_param_1: 130,
        algorithm_1_param_2: 140
    },
    "1:2:2:algorithm_11": {
        algorithm_11_param_1: 150,
        algorithm_11_param_2: 160
    },
    "2:::algorithm_C": {
        algorithm_C_param_1: 1.3,
        algorithm_C_param_2: 1.4
    },
    "2:::algorithm_D": {
        algorithm_D_param_1: 1.5,
        algorithm_D_param_2: 1.6
    },
    "2:1:1:algorithm_1": {
        algorithm_1_param_1: 170,
        algorithm_1_param_2: 180
    },
    "2:1:1:algorithm_11": {
        algorithm_11_param_1: 190,
        algorithm_11_param_2: 200
    },
    "2:1::algorithm_a": {
        algorithm_a_param_1: 1.7,
        algorithm_a_param_2: 1.8
    },
    "2:1::algorithm_b": {
        algorithm_b_param_1: 1.9,
        algorithm_b_param_2: 2
    },
    "2:1:2:algorithm_1": {
        algorithm_1_param_1: 210,
        algorithm_1_param_2: 220
    },
    "2:1:2:algorithm_11": {
        algorithm_11_param_1: 230,
        algorithm_11_param_2: 240
    },
    "2:2:1:algorithm_1": {
        algorithm_1_param_1: 250,
        algorithm_1_param_2: 260
    },
    "2:2:1:algorithm_11": {
        algorithm_11_param_1: 270,
        algorithm_11_param_2: 280
    },
    "2:2::algorithm_a": {
        algorithm_a_param_1: 2.1,
        algorithm_a_param_2: 2.2
    },
    "2:2::algorithm_b": {
        algorithm_b_param_1: 2.3,
        algorithm_b_param_2: 2.4
    },
    "2:2:2:algorithm_1": {
        algorithm_1_param_1: 290,
        algorithm_1_param_2: 300
    },
    "2:2:2:algorithm_11": {
        algorithm_11_param_1: 310,
        algorithm_11_param_2: 320
    }
}
```

Help please :( Thank you!

What I tried was to get the array with the keys:

```
var ruleIds = [...new Set([...object.set.subset.flatMap(subset => subset.algorithms.flatMap(alg => `${subset.subset_X}:::${alg.type}`).concat(subset.subset_collection.flatMap(col => col.algorithms.flatMap(alg => `${subset.subset_X}:${col.collection_X}::${alg.type}`).concat(col.collection_subcollection.flatMap(subCol => subCol.algorithms.flatMap(alg => `${subset.subset_X}:${col.collection_X}:${subCol.startBit}:${alg.type}`))))))])]
```

Wanted to obtain:

```
["1:::algorithm_A", "1:::algorithm_A", "1:1:1:algorithm_1" ..... ]
```

But after that I don't know how to add the parameters...

Comment: where is the problem with your code? do you control the input object? the input object and expected output exhibit misunderstanding of how objects and arrays should be used.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not include an attempt to solve the problem

Comment: It's not a problem with my code, but after several times I've tried to transform it in order to obtain the second object...I failed succeeding it :(

Comment: please include the code attempts to transform the input. where do the attempts fail?

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion to perform a depth-first traversal in your data structure.

I made some assumptions about the data structure, including:

- the "leaves" of this tree always have a "params" property.
- Other nodes in the tree have at the most 2 properties, of which exactly one is an array. The other optional property defines a part for the path
- As the above is not true for the top node (as `object` does not have an array property), this implementation needs to be called with the child property, `object.set`.

I have used a generator, so the called can construct an array from it with `Array.from`:

```js
function * flatten(object, path = "") {
    if ("params" in object) return yield { [path + object.type]: object.params };
    let entries = Object.entries(object);
    if (entries.length > 2 || !entries.length) throw "unexpected object structure";
    if (entries.length < 2) entries.unshift(["", ""]); // e.g. "set" has no path-element property
    else if (Array.isArray(entries[0][1])) entries.reverse();
    let [id, arr] = entries.map(([, v]) => v);
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) throw "unexpected object structure";
    for (let child of arr) {
        yield * flatten(child, id ? path + id + ":" : path);
    }
}

// The example input given in the question:
const object = {set: {subset: [{subset_X: 1,subset_collection: [{collection_X: 1,collection_subcollection: [{start: 1,algorithms: [{type: "algorithm_1",params: {algorithm_1_param_1: 10,algorithm_1_param_2: 20}},{type: "algorithm_11",params: {algorithm_11_param_1: 30,algorithm_11_param_2: 40}}]},{start: 2,algorithms: [{type: "algorithm_1",params: {algorithm_1_param_1: 50,algorithm_1_param_2: 60}},{type: "algorithm_11",params: {algorithm_11_param_1: 70,algorithm_11_param_2: 80}}]}]},{collection_X: 2,collection_subcollection: [{start: 1,algorithms: [{type: "algorithm_1",params: {algorithm_1_param_1: 90,algorithm_1_param_2: 100}},{type: "algorithm_11",params: {algorithm_11_param_1: 110,algorithm_11_param_2: 120}}]},{start: 2,algorithms: [{type: "algorithm_1",params: {algorithm_1_param_1: 130,algorithm_1_param_2: 140}},{type: "algorithm_11",params: {algorithm_11_param_1: 150,algorithm_11_param_2: 160}}]}]}]},{subset_X: 2,subset_collection: [{collection_X: 1,collection_subcollection: [{start: 1,algorithms: [{type: "algorithm_1",params: {algorithm_1_param_1: 170,algorithm_1_param_2: 180}},{type: "algorithm_11",params: {algorithm_11_param_1: 190,algorithm_11_param_2: 200}}]},{start: 2,algorithms: [{type: "algorithm_1",params: {algorithm_1_param_1: 210,algorithm_1_param_2: 220}},{type: "algorithm_11",params: {algorithm_11_param_1: 230,algorithm_11_param_2: 240}}]}]},{collection_X: 2,collection_subcollection: [{start: 1,algorithms: [{type: "algorithm_1",params: {algorithm_1_param_1: 250,algorithm_1_param_2: 260}},{type: "algorithm_11",params: {algorithm_11_param_1: 270,algorithm_11_param_2: 280}}]},{start: 2,algorithms: [{type: "algorithm_1",params: {algorithm_1_param_1: 290,algorithm_1_param_2: 300}},{type: "algorithm_11",params: {algorithm_11_param_1: 310,algorithm_11_param_2: 320}}]}]}]}]}};

let result = Array.from(flatten(object.set));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm looking for something much simpler, smthg using reduce, flatMap...
PS: I modified the object.. and the result

Comment: Good luck with doing it "much simpler".